# How to pass ForeignKey in dict to create Model object. Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created one model to store User name and place

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    place = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASECADE)
```

I have one JSON file there I have data of more than 1000 users. like

```
[
    {"name": "A", "place":1},
    {"name": "B", "place":3},
    {"name": "C", "place":4},
    {"name": "D", "place":1},
    ..
    ..
]
```

There place field is related to City object id. When I am using below syntax

```
UserDetails.objects.create(**{"name":"A", "place": 3})
```

then getting an error, I know instead of passing place id I have to pass obj like:

```
loc = City.object.get(id=3)
UserDetails.objects.create(**{"name":"A", "place": loc})
```

This is fine, but I have a large amount of data how can I pass place id or should use bulk_create to save all JSON data in model?

Comment: Why use ```UserDetails.objects.create()``` as opposed to simply doing ```UserDetails()```?

Comment: @EdwinCruz: the `UserDetails(...)` constructor does not save the objects to the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know, you simply call the ```save()``` on it. I just always find myself using ```UserDetails( . . . )``` as opposed to ```UserDetails.objects.create( . . . )```. Thought there was a good reason rather than just preference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `place_id` instead, this is the "twin field" Django creates that is stored in the database, and stores a reference (usually the primarh key) to the target model, given of course such `Place` already exists:

```
user_details = [
    UserDetails(name=record['name'], place_id=record['place'])
    for record in list_of_records
]
UserDetails.object.bulk_create(user_details)
```

Here the `list_of_records` is thus your list of dictionaries. We can make use of [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to add all `UserDetails` in a small number of insert queries.

Comment: Hi @willem, your solution is working thank you......, now if I change field "place" with "place_id", Is there any syntax for bulk create when I pass a list of user_info dict data? as I mentioned in the user data list example... I am asking this coz what you have suggested.
     "user_details = [
    UserDetails(name=record['name'], place_id=record['place'])
    for record in list_of_records
]"....
will take time to process all data by "for loop". 
Is there any method like ...create(**data) where I can pass that list.

Comment: @ShivShankarKeshari: the time that this takes is neglegible, especially since the creation of the query (the `.bulk_create` part) will also work with a for loop. After all the loop here is not the bottleneck. Often this is the number of round trips to the database.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working:

```
def model_to_dict_wfk(modelobj):
    opts = modelobj._meta.fields
    modeldict = model_to_dict(modelobj)
    for m in opts:
        if m.is_relation:
            foreignkey = getattr(modelobj, m.name)
            if foreignkey:
                try:
                    modeldict[m.name] = foreignkey
                except:
                    pass
    return modeldict
```

then use the returned dictionary in the create classmethod

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, vals):
    obj = cls(**vals)
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

Comment: If would be helpful if you could explain what is happening in the code.

Comment: It returns a dictionary with foreign keys as objects rather than ids and this allows to save it by passing the dictionary as **vals

Comment: I meant you can explain it in your post :)